# How to populate input fields using Json file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am trying to populate html form fields automatically. Based on what user selects in first field, other input fields are filled automatically. I was able to get code for related functions (fetch json data, creating dropdown list from json data) through my friend. Here is the link to that code
`enter code here`"https://jsfiddle.net/r4zuy7tn/1/" . i have added code in question also.

But unfortunately,  in his code,  he has used dynamic input fields. and I am not comfortable with using Dynamic fields. therefore I tried to edit some parts of the code (i got through my friend) so that i could make this code to automatically fill values in manually created input fields rather than creating dynamic input fields and than populating them. but failed in this as i don't  know about coding enough.

can someone please help me to accomplish this task?
i just need to add some different function in the code (javascript) which could populate manually created input fields rather than creating dynamic fields.
any help will be appreciated...

```js
// define the headings here, so we can access it globally
// in the app
let headings = []

// appending the created HTML string to the DOM
function initInputs(headingList) {
  jQuery(".fields").append(createInputsHTML(headingList))
}

// the HTMLT template that is going to be appended
// to the DOM
function createInputsHTML(headingList) {
  let html = ''
  headingList.forEach(heading => {
    if (heading !== 'Company') {
      html += `<label for="${heading}">${heading}: </label>`
      html += `<input id="${heading}">`
      html += '<br>'
    }
  })

  return html
}

// receiving data
// this data arrives later in the app's lifecycle,
// so it's the best to return a Promise object
// that gets resolved (check JS Promise for more information)
function getJSON() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    jQuery.get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.coasilat.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/data-1.txt", function(data) {
      resolve(JSON.parse(data))
    });
  })
}

// processing raw JSON data
function processRawData(data) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const companyData = []
    // creating data array
    // handling multiple sheets
    Object.values(data).forEach((sheet, index) => {
      sheet.forEach((company, i) => {
        companyData.push({ ...company
        })
        // create headings only once
        if (index === 0 && i === 0) {
          Object.keys(company).forEach(item => {
            headings.push(item.trim())
          })
        }
      })
    })
    resolve(companyData)
  })
}

$(async function() {

  let lists = [];

  function initAutocomplete(list) {
    const thisKey = 'Company'
    $("#company").autocomplete('option', 'source', function(request, response) {
      response(
        list.filter(item => {
          if (item[thisKey].toLowerCase().includes(request.term.toLowerCase())) {
            item.label = item[thisKey]
            return item
          }
        })
      )
    })
  }

  $("#company").autocomplete({
    minLength: 3,
    source: lists,
    focus: function(event, ui) {
      // the "species" is constant - it shouldn't be modified
      $("#company").val(ui.item.Company);
      return false;
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
      // handling n number of fields / columns
      headings.forEach(heading => {
        $('#' + heading).val(ui.item[heading])
      })
      return false;
    }
  });

  // starting data download, processing and usage
  getJSON()
    .then(json => {
      return processRawData(json)
    })
    .then(data => {
      // just so we see what data we are using
      console.log(data)
      // make the processed data accessible globally
      lists = data
      initAutocomplete(lists)
      initInputs(headings)
    })

});

// this is how you get values form the form
document.getElementById('btnListValues').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  formGetValues('frm1')
})
// this is how you reset the form
document.getElementById('btnResetForm').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  formSetValues('frm1', '')
})

function formSetValues(formId, val) {
  const formEl = document.getElementById(formId).elements
  for (let i = 0; i < formEl.length; i++) {
    formEl[i].value = val
  }
}

function formGetValues(formId) {
  const formEl = document.getElementById(formId).elements
  for (let el of formEl) {
    console.log(el.value)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="ui-widget">
  <form id="frm1">
    <label for="company">Company: </label>
    <input id="company"><br />
    <div class="fields"></div>

<!-- below given input fields are those ones which i wanted to prefill, rather than creating dynamic fields. but my friend added that kind of function in javascript which firstly creates dynamic input fields and then populate them automatically.....

 
 
1) PE Ratio
    <input type="number"  id="PE" /><br>
    2)Price/Book 
     <input type="number"  id="PB" /><br> 
    3)ROCE
    <input type="number" id="ROCE" /><br>
    4) Sales Growth
     <input type="number" id="SG" /> <br> 
    5) NPM 
  <input type="number" id="NPM" /><br>
  6) ROA
    <input type="number" id="ROA" /><br> 
    7) Dividend Yield <input type="number" id="DY" /><br>
  8) Debt/Equity
   <input type="number" id="DE" /><br> 
 9)Price/Sales 
  <input type="number" id="PS" /><br> 
  10) Unpledge Promoter Stake
   <input type="number" id="UPS" /><br> 
11) Current Ratio
  <input type="number" id="CR" /><br> 
   <br /> 
   -->
  </form>
</div>
<input id="btnListValues" type="button" value="List values">
<input id="btnResetForm" type="button" value="Reset form">
```

Comment: Please post a working example after reading: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the question (use the snippet editor).

Comment: randy casburn  i have now added working example in my question :)

Answer (score 0):

I just uncommented your input fields as

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <form id="frm1">
      <label for="company">Company: </label>
      <input id="company"><br />
      <div class="fields"></div>

  <!-- below decscribed input fields are those ones which i wanted to prefill, rather than creating dynamic fields. but my friend added such kind of function in javascript which firstly creates dynamic input fields and then populate them automatically.....-->



  1) PE Ratio
      <input type="number"  id="PE" /><br>
      2)Price/Book 
       <input type="number"  id="PB" /><br> 
      3)ROCE
      <input type="number" id="ROCE" /><br>
      4) Sales Growth
       <input type="number" id="SG" /> <br> 
      5) NPM 
    <input type="number" id="NPM" /><br>
    6) ROA
      <input type="number" id="ROA" /><br> 
      7) Dividend Yield <input type="number" id="DY" /><br>
    8) Debt/Equity
     <input type="number" id="DE" /><br> 
   9)Price/Sales 
    <input type="number" id="PS" /><br> 
    10) Unpledge Promoter Stake
     <input type="number" id="UPS" /><br> 
  11) Current Ratio
    <input type="number" id="CR" /><br> 
     <br /> 

    </form>
  </div>
  <input id="btnListValues" type="button" value="List values">
  <input id="btnResetForm" type="button" value="Reset form">
```

Then commented all those function resulting dynamic field generation as

```
<script>
  // define the headings here, so we can access it globally
// in the app
let headings = []

// appending the created HTML string to the DOM
/* commented here function initInputs(headingList) {
  jQuery(".fields").append(createInputsHTML(headingList))
} */

// the HTMLT template that is going to be appended
// to the DOM
/* Commented here function createInputsHTML(headingList) {

  let html = ''
  headingList.forEach(heading => {
    if (heading !== 'Company') {
      html += `<label for="${heading}">${heading}: </label>`
      html += `<input id="${heading}">`
      html += '<br>'
    }
  })

  return html
} */

// receiving data
// this data arrives later in the app's lifecycle,
// so it's the best to return a Promise object
// that gets resolved (check JS Promise for more information)
function getJSON() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    jQuery.get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.coasilat.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/data-1.txt", function(data) {
      resolve(JSON.parse(data))
    });
  })
}

// processing raw JSON data
function processRawData(data) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const companyData = []
    // creating data array
    // handling multiple sheets
    Object.values(data).forEach((sheet, index) => {
      sheet.forEach((company, i) => {
        companyData.push({ ...company
        })
        // create headings only once
        if (index === 0 && i === 0) {
          Object.keys(company).forEach(item => {
            headings.push(item.trim())
          })
        }
      })
    })
    resolve(companyData)
  })
}

$(async function() {

  let lists = [];

  function initAutocomplete(list) {
    const thisKey = 'Company'
    $("#company").autocomplete('option', 'source', function(request, response) {
      response(
        list.filter(item => {
          if (item[thisKey].toLowerCase().includes(request.term.toLowerCase())) {
            item.label = item[thisKey]
            return item
          }
        })
      )
    })
  }

  $("#company").autocomplete({
    minLength: 3,
    source: lists,
    focus: function(event, ui) {
      // the "species" is constant - it shouldn't be modified
      $("#company").val(ui.item.Company);
      return false;
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
      // handling n number of fields / columns
      headings.forEach(heading => {
        $('#' + heading).val(ui.item[heading])
      })
      return false;
    }
  });

  // starting data download, processing and usage
  getJSON()
    .then(json => {
      return processRawData(json)
    })
    .then(data => {
      // just so we see what data we are using
      console.log(data)
      // make the processed data accessible globally
      lists = data
      initAutocomplete(lists)
     //commented here initInputs(headings)
    })

});

// this is how you get values form the form
document.getElementById('btnListValues').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  formGetValues('frm1')
})
// this is how you reset the form
document.getElementById('btnResetForm').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  formSetValues('frm1', '')
})

function formSetValues(formId, val) {
  const formEl = document.getElementById(formId).elements
  for (let i = 0; i < formEl.length; i++) {
    formEl[i].value = val
  }
}

function formGetValues(formId) {
  const formEl = document.getElementById(formId).elements
  for (let el of formEl) {
    console.log(el.value)
  }
}
  </script>
```

Everything works fine.Your code was absolutely correct if you were manually creating html fields then there was no need of functions causing dynamic field generation.I hope this is what all you need.

Comment: bipin thakur  in your code, dropdown function is not working. additionally, i need to prefill values of other input fields based on selected option from first input field. thanks